# DateEdit show time picker

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

How can I show time picker inside `DevExpress.XtraEditors.DateEdit`? I want to select time dynamically.

Comment: How come my answer didn't fit You and You accepted the other one ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

to show  TimePicker you should set `VistaDisplayMode` and `VistaEditTime` properties to `true`
and don't forget to change `EditFormat` , `DisplayFormat` and `EditMask` to any DateTime Format, for example: `"dd.M.y hh:mm"`

Answer (score 11):

Assuming dateEdit is the name of Your control:

```
  dateEdit.Properties.VistaDisplayMode = DefaultBoolean.True;
  dateEdit.Properties.VistaEditTime = DefaultBoolean.True;
```

[image: DateEdit VistaDisplayMode and VistaEditTime]

Comment: Does this answer Your question ?

Comment: Thanks Marty for your response, Emin has already answered question.